# VueJs Url Rewrite Error when hosting on IIS with ASP.net Core 2.0 application

Tags: vue.js, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-8

I am hosting `vuejs` app inside `WWWROOT` folder of Asp.net Core 2.0 App.

When i try to run the application with the url:

https://admin.myapp.com or https://admin.myapp.com/index, when https://admin.myapp.com is hit on the browser the application should be redirected to ../index but nothing is happening. Their is always a below error on the browser console.

`manifest.c93377026a31fd19d204.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < vendor.ce0b0308730c78917196.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < app.09cbf8437d50e73c0697.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

I am rewriting the URL as follows in the web config files of the application.

`Web Config` Outside the wwwroot folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="VueJs Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(account)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="C:\logs\MYApp\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My Startup class:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{

    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

    //app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    //app.UseHangfireServer();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    InitializeAsync(app.ApplicationServices, CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseAuthentication();


    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    //app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

In VueJs i am using `history` mode.

This is the small piece of code which i am using in my Route.js

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: "history",
  linkActiveClass: "open active",
  scrollBehavior: () => ({ y: 0 }),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      redirect: "/index",
      name: "Home",
      component: Full
```

When i try browsing the app using the URL(api URL) like

`https://admin.myapp.com/account/getdata`
`https://admin.myapp.com/api/list/state`

the data are populated correctly.

Any Suggestion or Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this aakash? I'm having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the below code on web config which solved my problem above. I have posted all the tag here as the answer. Hopefully this will help someone with the similar problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="wwwroot-static" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/{R:1}" />
        </rule> 

        <rule name="empty-root-index" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/index.html" />
        </rule>

        <!-- 
             Make sure you have a <base href="/" /> tag to fix the root path 
             or all relative links will break on rewrite 
        -->
        <rule name="AngularJS-Html5-Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/.well-known/openid-configuration" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/.well-known/jwks" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/api(.*)" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/account(.*)" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/connect(.*)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/index.html"  />
        </rule> 
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <handlers>
      <add name="StaticFileModuleHtml" path="*.htm*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="StaticFileModuleSvg" path="*.svg" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="StaticFileModuleJs" path="*.js" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="StaticFileModuleCss" path="*.css" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="StaticFileModuleJpeg" path="*.jpeg" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="StaticFileModuleJpg" path="*.jpg" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="StaticFileModulePng" path="*.png" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="StaticFileModuleGif" path="*.gif" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
                stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can read more here at the [blog](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Apr/27/IIS-and-ASPNET-Core-Rewrite-Rules-for-Static-Files-and-Html-5-Routing).

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that Vue, by default, is assuming that your app is hosted at the base of your domain (`https://admin.myapp.com`). But when you deploy it as part of an ASP.NET project, it ends up sitting in a folder (`https://admin.myapp.com/wwwroot`). When the application files are being requested, they are not being detected as existing files by IIS Rewrite (because they aren't - relative to the base) and are being rewritten to index.html.

Try changing the [baseUrl](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl) value in your Vue config to '/wwwroot/'.

*(NOTE: The application I'm working on actually had a separate API project/site, so my solution was to just host the Vue frontend directly rather than embed it in an ASP.NET project. Pretty sure this is the answer, though.)*